# Flat rate shipping broken

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods

Magento 2 should have an option for flat rate shipping in

```
stores -> config -> sales -> shipping methods
```

My install  missing this option. There are 2 shipping methods available: Fedex and UPS, which are both enabled in the Component Manager. I'm using Magento 2.0.4

I can't find any component in the Component Manager that looks like it might have anything to do with flat rate shipping.

My client only has one shipping method, a flat rate £15 per order and that's what I want to set up.

Is there something wrong with my setup? 
Otherwise please can someone tell me how to set up the flat rate?

Answer (score 0):

It's not broken, the shipping is ONLY available for products that have weight set to Yes.

Configure it in your product details.

[image]